# What is the purpose of hard binding when explicit binding alone seems to guarantee that the this context of the callback can't be overwritten?

Tags: javascript

I'm following along the YDKJS books series by Kyle Simpson and had a question about explicit vs hard binding. Kyle explains that explicit binding alone isn't necessarily enough to guarantee that a function which we pass a callback to will preserve the `this` context of the callback. He cites examples of cases where functions in libraries/frameworks sometimes irritatingly force what `this` refers to in the callback you pass it to equal something other than what you explicitly set it to. So I tried to test out what this might look like, and I assumed that the following code would behave differently:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this.a);
}
var obj = {
    a: 5
}
var obj2 = {
    a: 10
}
function bar(f) {
    f.call(obj2); // 5 --> expected explicit binding to be overwritten here, but this doesn't happen (expected 10 and got 5)
}
bar(foo.bind(obj)); // explicit binding made here
```

I thought that this would successfully overwrite what `this` refers to (and that this is the reason why we need hard binding). First of all, here's the corresponding example using hard binding.

```
    function foo() {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
    var obj = {
        a: 5
    }
    var obj2 = {
        a: 10
    }
    // hard binding here
    function baz() {
        foo.call(obj);
    }
    function bar(f) {
        f.call(obj2); // 5 --> Here, it makes sense that we would get 5
    }
    bar(baz);
```

Let me explain what I thought the purpose of hard binding is:

I thought that it would be possible for bar to overwrite the `this` context of the callback. Indeed, Kyle Simpson himself suggests that this is possible and the reason for hard binding in the first place. Hard binding solves this problem that apparently exists because even if bar forcibly changes the `this` context of the callback baz, changing what baz's `this` refers to doesn't actually do anything, as it doesn't affect what `this` refers to in `foo.call(obj)` and that cannot be changed by bar.

However, I'm trying to reproduce this scenario where explicit binding fails, but can't seem to do so. I can't overwrite a function's `this` context even if it isn't hard-bound and only explicitly bound. Any ideas where my thinking is leading me astray?

Edit: When I'm not passing a function as a callback, in the global scope I can do `foo.call(obj)` and get 5, then do `foo.call(obj2)` and get 10, but that's not overwriting? Those are just two different instances of foo calls with different *this* bindings.

Comment: I haven't read that section but maybe he was referring to the fact that libraries make important information available via `this` in callbacks (and only that way) and with "explicit" binding you wouldn't have access to that information. You are certainly right that once a function is bound to a specific `this` value via `.bind` (which returns a new bound function btw), no matter how that function is called, that value cannot be overwritten.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the response. He explicitly mentions that code which isn't yours, e.g., a function in a library or framework, can actually change what _this_ refers to in a callback that you pass it _even if you explicitly bind it_. He claims that the solution to this problem is the hard binding pattern you see above. So I imagined a scenario where explicit binding can be overwritten, and it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Can you link to that section? *"So I imagined a scenario where explicit binding can be overwritten"* As I said, bound functions cannot have a `this` value other than the one they were bound to.

Comment: @FelixKling The quoted part of your comment is me speaking, not Kyle. He does say this in the book: "Unfortunately, _explicit binding_ alone still doesn't offer any solution to the issue mentioned previously, of a function "losing" its intended _this_ binding, or just having it paved over by a framework, etc." Page 18 (I'm not sure how I'd link it; I only have a physical copy). He goes on to say "But a variation pattern around explicit binding actually does the trick" and then goes into hard binding.

Comment: "It's quite common that our function callbacks _lose_ their _this_ binding... But another way that _this_ can surprise us is when the function we've passed our callback to intentionally changes the _this_ for the call. Event handlers in popular JavaScript libraries are quite fond of forcing your callback to have a _this_ that points to, for instance, the DOM element that triggered the event...Either way the _this_ is changed unexpectedly, you are not really in control of how your callback function reference will be executed...We'll see shortly a way of "fixing" that problem." AKA hard binding

Comment: I don't know which edition you are reading but [this one](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#hard-binding) refers to `.bind` as *hard* binding and using `.call` as *explicit* binding. Following that terminology, both of your examples use hard binding. And this makes actually sense: A library function might not actually call the function with "explicit" binding and thus you don't have a way to control the value of `this`.

Comment: @FelixKling You know what...you're right. I think my edition is slightly different, but I realize now why I was mislead. I assumed that .bind() was just an example of explicit binding and not hard binding. He means that .call() and .apply() alone don't solve the problem mentioned above (which makes sense).

Comment: Glad we were able to clarify this :)

Comment: @FelixKling hi guys... take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments, I did some research and testing trying to break `bind` method and found that, when a bound function is called by using the `new` operator, pre-assigned `this` value is ignored and prepended arguments are kept.

So, there is absolutely a way to change a previously bound `this` of a function (see script below) and OPs 'hard bind' example avoids it!

I must note that I also tried other ugly thing like `eval` without success.

Anyway, speaking about libraries, messing with user defined functions (or callbacks) contexts seems bad practice to me. Doing the following is madness, I don't think someone would do it. However, this is good to know for the sake of knowledge.

```js
const a = {value: 1};
const b = {value: 2};

const fn = function() {console.log(this.value);};

const boundA = fn.bind(a);
const hardBoundA = function() {fn.call(a);};

const reBoundB = (new boundA()).constructor.bind(b);
const hardReBoundB = (new hardBoundA()).constructor.bind(b);

boundA();
hardBoundA();

reBoundB()
hardReBoundB();
```

Comment: Interesting find. When a bound function is called with `new`, the bound `this` value is indeed ignored: https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget. If you think about it more it's not actually too surprising: The whole purpose of `new` is to create a new object and apply the constructor. That cannot happen with a bound function so the underlying function is called "normally" instead. Either way, that's not the case that was referred to in the book, it was simply a misunderstanding.